# Sequelize - How do I drop a database and restart

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am running an app with the database running locally. There seem to be issues with the database somewhere as cascading deletes are not working. I believe that there may be issues with the database being migrated/unmigrated incorrectly. I want to delete the database and start over - create, migrate, etc.

The issue that I am running into is that when I run the command `sequelize db:drop`, it gives me an error of ...

```
ERROR: Please install pg package manually
```

I added the package and then still got the error. I put in a require statement and still got the error.

I don't understand how sequelize can do an init, do migrations, and do other things and yet doesn't have a package needed to run the delete command? What do I do now? How can I delete the database and start over?

Comment: Did you install it globally?

Comment: Maybe. Why would I need to install it globally to delete, but not to do anything else?

Comment: I'm not sure how this works internally, but if it's complaining about a dependency when running a globally installed command, that's usually the solution.